# Symfony 2.3 cascade_validation

Tags: validation, symfony

i build a form in symfony 2.3. Which shows and save user profile and addresses for this profile. 
I have two entities. A user and a address entity. (I will only show some code parts, this code is not complete here)

### User Entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Ebm\UserBundle\Entity\UserRepository")
 */
class User implements AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable
{
      /**
      * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
      * @ORM\Id
      * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
      */
     protected $id;


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $firstName;


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $lastName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     * @Assert\Valid
      * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Ebm\UserBundle\Entity\Address", cascade={"persist",  "remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_address",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="address_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     */
    protected $addresses;
    }
```

### Address Entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="address")
 */
class Address
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $street;
}
```

And a form which embed the address entity as collection into the user form "usertype".

### Usertype:

```
class UserType extends AbstractType
{

    protected $securityContext;

    public function __construct(SecurityContext $securityContext)
    {
        $this->securityContext = $securityContext;
    }


    /**
     * (non-PHPdoc)
     * @see \Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType::buildForm()
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->->add('addresses', 'collection', array(
                        'type' => new AddressType() ,
                        'allow_add' => true, 
                        'allow_delete' => true,
                        'label' => false,
                        'cascade_validation' => true)
                      ));
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Ebm\UserBundle\Entity\User',
            'cascade_validation' => true,
    ));

}

public function getName()
{
        return 'user';
}
```

}

In my controller the validation part look like this:

```
    $form = $this->createForm($this->get('form.type.user'), $user)->add('save', 'submit');

    // On initial page load handleRequest() recognizes that the form was not submitted and does nothing
    // isValid returns false
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    // Check if form isValid
    if ($form->isValid()) {
    }
```

And my validation yml (UserBundle/config/validation.yml) file look like this

```
Ebm\UserBundle\Entity\User:
    properties:
        firstName:
            - NotBlank: ~
            - Length:
                max: 255
        addresses:
            - Valid: ~

Ebm\UserBundle\Entity\Address:
    properties:
        street:
            - NotBlank: { message: "validate.not_blank" }
            - Type:
                  type: string
            - Length:
                  max: 255
```

If the address field is emtyp "street" as example no error was occured. Only validation errors for 
entity "user" is displayed.

I'm looking since a week for a solution, i will be very lucky if anyone can help me

Comment: I think the validation is correct but it does not show the error messages from the embeded collections? Hava anyone an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**As of >= Symfony 2.5 you can use the deep parameter of `getErrors`**

If you want to display errors for compound forms use the `deep` parameter in the `getErrors()` function:

```
// Check if form isValid
if ($form->isValid() === false) {
    echo $form->getErrors(true);
}
```

Otherwise use the all function recursive:

```
public function getErrorsRecursive($form) {
    $errors = array();

    foreach ($form->getErrors() as $error) {
        $errors[] = $error->getMessage();
    }        

    foreach ($form->all() as $fieldName => $formType) {
        if ($errorMessage = $this->getErrorsRecursive($formType)) {
            $errors[$fieldName] = array_pop($errorMessage);
        }
    }

    return $errors;
}
```